# Setting up google-http-java-client in eclipse for android project

Tags: java, eclipse, google-http-client

I am trying to set up the google-http-java-client on eclipse (without utilizing maven) for an android application project.  After following the steps below, when attempting to import any of the com.google.api.services... or com.google.api.client... libraries (for instance, those listed in java sample examples on this page: https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/code_samples/java#create_a_playlist), I receive errors regarding unresolved imports.

Several points are not clear to me from the setup page (https://code.google.com/p/google-http-java-client/wiki/Setup) and the readme.html file that comes with the google-http-java-client zip file.  I'm assuming my error is in how I approached this process.

1) "Eclipse users will want to set the "Source attachment" for each class jar to its corresponding "-sources" jar."

I see the "-sources" jar files in a lib-sources folder in the google-http-java-client.zip file.  Also, I see the libs folder itself contains .jar.properties files for each .jar file.

I just added each of the needed .jar files to the lib folder in eclipse and added the lib-sources folder on the same level as the lib folder and put the corresponding .jar.sources files in it.

2) "The following are the jars from the dependencies folder required for android applications (or a newer compatible version of each dependency):

google-http-client-1.17.0-rc.jar
google-http-client-android-1.17.0-rc.jar
gson-2.1.jar
jackson-core-2.1.3.jar
jackson-core-asl-1.9.4.jar
jsr305-1.3.9.jar
protobuf-java-2.2.0.jar"

Does that mean these are the only files that are needed to be added for using google-http-java-client on android?

3) There is a section on the setup page regarding classpaths: "A .classpath file snippet that can be included in your project's .classpath has been provided here. Please only use the classpath entries you actually need (see below for details)."

Below I see:

"Android Dependencies

The following are the jars from the libs folder required for Android applications or a newer compatible version:     google-http-client-android-1.17.0-rc.jar"

I added this .jar file and others as described above.  Then I cleaned and rebuilt my project.  I also have the google-play-services_lib.jar added in the android dependencies on the project.

Sorry for the rudimentary question.  I'm not sure why the imports are still unresolved after taking these steps.  Any clarifications are greatly appreciated.